# Eigenvector Span Mn(R)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

DefineS: $ M_n(R) → M_n(R)$ by $S(A) = A^T$. Prove that S has only two distinct eigenvalues and that its eigenvectors span $ M_n(R)$. I got that by the trick of $S^2(A)=A=\lambda ^2A$, the two eigenvalues are 1 and-1. But how to show that it spans $M_n$. Thank you!

Comment: partly duplicate of (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/792079) and (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2117542)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the eigenvectors (or 'eigenmatrices') corresponding to $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = -1$? Note that if $\lambda = 1$, then $A = A^T$ so the eigenspace is the space of symmetric matrices. Similarly, if $\lambda = -1$ then $A = -A^T$ so the eigenspace is the space of all skew-symmetric matrices. We want to show that any matrix can be written as the sum of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices. You can check that for any matrix $A$, you can write $A$ as $A = \frac{A+A^T}{2} + \frac{A-A^T}{2}$. See if you can determine what kind of matrices these two terms are!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A=\frac{A+A^T}{2}+\frac{A-A^T}{2}$